# Better to have single butt joint or 2 tapered joints when hanging drywall?

Tags: drywall

I am in the process of hanging drywall for my basement.

Due to the length of the walls there are a couple situations where I could either hang the sheets to have a single butt joint.. or to have 2 tapered joints. Which one would be better for the mudder? I am planning on hiring out the mudding but have not hired anyone yet to ask. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are merits to both. For structural support (yes, drywall adds some shear support) you want fewer joints and drywall crossing as many studs as possible. This has the side benefit of reducing the amount of taping needed and may use less mud.

For visual appeal, tapered joints are easier to completely hide with mud. Rather than spreading out the mud over a wide area to minimize the visibility of the joint, you can completely fill the taper for a perfectly smooth transition.

Comment: And most guys mudding won't care which you pick.

Comment: Finisher here, +1 @DMoore: most of us charge by the square footage that we are finishing, plus any bead/trim. How you choose to join your seams, makes little, if any difference. Now, poorly hung, loose drywall, and crooked framing - are different stories altogether. (Note: vertical seams are usually easier to spot, after paint, than horizontal seams.)

Answer (score 0):

If your drywaller is good, it really isn't going to matter. That being said it is usually best practice to hang your drywaller horizontally not vertically.